# Worker calling a function doesn't print

Tags: julia

I am trying to debug a parallel program in Julia and would like to see print-outs from its workers, but they don't appear to be able to print. How can I "fix" this?

My test code is:

```
function Test()
  print("Worker ",myid())
end

for i in workers()
  @spawnat i Test()
end
```

Comment: If you rename your function to `mytest`, does it work for you then?

Answer (score 2):

The function `Test` is not defined on remote workers, you do not use `fetch` and hence it fails silently. Using `myid()` also requires loading `Distributed` at remote workers. Last but not least, the standard output on remote workers is cached on line level and hence you need to use `println` instead of `print`.

Here is the correct code:

```
using Distributed
@everywhere Distributed
@everywhere function Test()
    println("Worker ",myid())
end

for i in workers()
    fetch(@spawnat i Test())
end
```

Following Bogumil's comment - `fetch` is here so your code does not fail silently because for some other reason. You will need to use @async and @sync macros to collect the data:

```
jobs = Dict{Int,Future}()
@sync for i in workers()
    @async jobs[i] = @spawnat i Test()
end

@sync for i in workers()
    @async fetch(jobs[i])
end
```

Comment: Probably it makes more sense to add `@sync` in front of for-loop instead of `fetch`, as `fetch` in this place destroys all benefits from parallel code (in this case it does not matter of course, but if the actual function did some work it would).